# reading huge csv files with illegal EOL marker

Tags: r

I need to read several huge(>400MB) csv log files into R. The file looks like:

> N  VISIT_DATE  REQ_URL TYPE_LEVEL
>
> 126424 2013/1/25 23:42:34  http://weibo.cn/attgroup/privateAtt?cat=user&f=atts 1
>
> 33559  2013/1/25 15:15:54  http://i.ifeng.com/mil/mili?vt=5&dh=touch&mid=aKUiAg    1

I use the following command to readin the content of the csv files. It works fine for most of the data. However, there are some illegal characters in some of the `REQ_URL` field like `http://some.url/query=_1A_` where 1A is the hex code which is quite similar as the LF marker. It seems that the `scan` function treats these characters as EOL markers and stops when meets them. Is there any way to let R ignore these characters or being treated as EOL marker? Thx.

> dat<-scan(file='sample.sv', 
>            what=list("integer", "numeric", "character", "integer"), 
>            sep='\t', strip.white=T, quote="", 
>            multi.line=F, skip=1)

Comment: Why not to use `read.table` here?

Comment: The log files are huge in size(> 400MB), `read.table` may cause R to collapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fread` similar to read.table but faster and more convenient.

```
TEXT <- '126424 2013/1/25 23:42:34 http://weibo.cn/attgroup/privateAtt?cat=user&f=atts 1
33559 2013/1/25 15:15:54 http://i.ifeng.com/mil/mili?vt=5&dh=touch&mid=aKUiAg 1
33556 2013/1/25 15:15:59 http://some.url/query=_1A_ 1'
library(data.table)
fread(TEXT)
       V1        V2       V3                                                   V4 V5
1: 126424 2013/1/25 23:42:34  http://weibo.cn/attgroup/privateAtt?cat=user&f=atts  1
2:  33559 2013/1/25 15:15:54 http://i.ifeng.com/mil/mili?vt=5&dh=touch&mid=aKUiAg  1
3:  33556 2013/1/25 15:15:59                           http://some.url/query=_1A_  1
```